# The sum of series in an interval

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following series -

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{2n-1}
$$
I found that its convergence interval is $[-1,1]$ but how can i calculate the 
sum in this interval ? i would like to get some hint for those kind of exercises.

Comment: The *radius of convergence* is 1, but be aware that the "interval of convergence" is $(-1,1)$, not $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

For $\;|x|<1\;$ :

$$\frac1{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}\stackrel{\text{diff.}}\implies\frac{2x}{(1-x^2)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2n\,x^{2n-1}$$

Now just do a little cosmetics to the above and get your answer.

Comment: can u please explain the transition in the equation?

Comment: It is written there: differentiation. We know that within the convergence interval of a series of differentiable functions we can differentiate term-term the series. That's exactly what I did, and the left hand's derivative is easy.

Comment: Ok , so should I generally just plug the x values ?

Comment: @GeorgeB Sorry, I doon't understand your question. What values are you talking about? Of $\;x\;$ ? Yes, as long as it is $\;|x|<1\;$ it works perfectly well.

Comment: So when I need to find the sum of a series in an interval - i just need to find the interval and the representing power series?

Comment: @GeorgeB It is usually tougher than that, as many times you have no the slightest idea what function, if at all, of the more or less well-known, more or less basic functions, a converging series represents, but if you can find a nice function represented by a series, then yes. As long as $\;x\;$ is **within** the convergence interval